# Extract attribute 'value' from BeautifulSoup xml

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract search keywords from SOAP [xml schema](http://ecp.iedadata.org/soap_search_schema.xsd) with BeautifulSoup and cannot figure out how to extract value attributes.

I have tried using `soap.find_all` but it will not let me extract the value attribute.

Here is what I have so far:

```
soap = requests.get('http://ecp.iedadata.org/soap_search_schema.xsd')
soapXML = soap.content.decode("utf-8")
soapSoup = BeautifulSoup(soapXML, "xml")
level1 = soapSoup.findAll('xs:attribute', {'name':'level1'})[0]
level1['value']
```

And this is where I have an issue. According to BeautifulSoup documentation this should output all the 'value' attributes.

```
print(level1):

<xs:attribute name="level1" use="optional">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value=""/>
<xs:enumeration value="alteration"/>
<xs:enumeration value="igneous"/>
<xs:enumeration value="metamorphic"/>
<xs:enumeration value="notfound"/>
<xs:enumeration value="ore"/>
<xs:enumeration value="sedimentary"/>
<xs:enumeration value="vein"/>
<xs:enumeration value="xenolith"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

So as you can see, I am trying to get the text from the value attribute in all of the xs:enumeration tags. The end result would be a list of search terms for level1. i.e.:

(alteration, igneous, metamorphic, notfound, ore, sedimentary, vein, xenolith)

I cannot just call on the xs:enumeration tag as there are multiple keywords (i.e. level2, level3, SampleType... etc.) and each have different xs:enumeration values.

Here is the error on the last line (level1['value'])

> ---
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 level1test['value']
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py in **getitem**(self, key)
>      1069         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
>      1070         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
>   -> 1071         return self.attrs[key]
>      1072 
>      1073     def **iter**(self):
>
> KeyError: 'value'

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `level1['value']` with:

```
for i in level1:
    if type(i) is not bs4.element.NavigableString:
        data = i.contents
        for k in data[1]:
            if type(k) is not bs4.element.NavigableString:
                print(k['value'])
```

Output:

```
alteration
igneous
metamorphic
notfound
ore
sedimentary
vein
xenolith
```

Comment: @DeltaV - Just tried it with `import bs4` and `soapSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(soapXML, "xml")` and it, too, works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the *value* [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soap = requests.get('http://ecp.iedadata.org/soap_search_schema.xsd')
soapXML = soap.content.decode("utf-8")
soapSoup =bs(soapXML, "xml")
enumeration_values = [item['value'] for item in  soapSoup.select("[value]") if item['value']]
print(enumeration_values)
```

Marginally **faster** would be to use the [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/type_selectors)

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soap = requests.get('http://ecp.iedadata.org/soap_search_schema.xsd')
soapXML = soap.content.decode("utf-8")
soapSoup =bs(soapXML, "xml")
enumeration_values = [item['value'] for item in  soapSoup.select("enumeration") if item['value']]
print(enumeration_values)
```